# sql server sql query

Tags: sql-server

in my application user can give username or emailid to login how can i write the query like

```
select username,password from employee
where username='xxxx' or 'xxxx@yahoo.com' and password='******'
```

how can i write the query so that user can give username or emailid to login.
please send query for this problem thank u

Comment: @surya: then you should do the polite and proper thing and accept the best answer / the one that really solved you problem. To accept the answer, please click on the check mark to the left of the answer below the "0" with the up- and down-arrow. If someone helps you - please be so kind as to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given the query already.
The only thing you need to do, is add braces so that the conditiosn are logically grouped together so that  ...

Like this:

```
WHERE ( username = '' and password = '' ) or (email = '' and password = '' )
```

Comment: @surya: then you should do the polite and proper thing and accept the answer - click on the check mark to the left of the answer below the "0" with the up- and down-arrow. If someone helps you - please be so kind as to accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

```
select username,password from employee where (username='xxxx' or username='xxxx@yahoo.com') and password='******'
```

Why?
There was operator precedence bug:

```
A or B and C === A or (B and C)
```

When no brackets specified AND operator has 1st priority.
In boolean math AND op is like multiplication and OR op like addition in regular math.

Comment: You are welcome! Question answer mark would be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select username,password from employee 
where (username='xxxx' and password='******') 
or (username='xxxx@yahoo.com' and password='******')
```